# How do I check for two requirements when logging in using Django?

Tags: python, django

I know that I can use user.is_authenticated in templates to only display content to authenticated users. However, how can I throw an error if a field that I have is false? The field is "approved" (user.profile.approved).

I'm not exactly sure where I might put a decorator to check for this.

Comment: What about `{% if user.is_authenticated and user.profile.approved %}`?

Comment: I'd like to throw an alert-danger on the login page. If I use those settings on the login page, no one can access it. Correct?

Comment: It's simply not possible to display  `user.profile.approved` before a user is logged in.

Comment: Right. When a user tries to log in, Django checks for is_active. If false, then they can't log in. Can I do the same with my custom field?

Comment: always do authentication and verification in views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom authentication backend like so:

django_site/backends.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend


class ProfileCheckBackend(ModelBackend):

    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        is_active = super().user_can_authenticate(user)
        return is_active and getattr(user.profile, "approved", False)
```

now replace ModelBackend in your settings.py module with your new backend:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
      "django_site.backends.ProfileCheckBackend"
]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you for doing that. I'm assuming that it inherits from ModelBackend and still checks against Django's list of “authentication backends," correct? Also, would **profile_check_backend** be a python file?

Comment: Interesting. AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = does not exist in my settings.py file

Comment: Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: 
d doesn't look like a module path

Comment: Exception Value: 
No module named '<django_site>'

Comment: I've simplified the example (read it again carefully) and included a screenshot of the project structure

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! :) Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Only my pleasure!

Comment: Although, now users can't sign up, but I'll try to figure that out.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion here https://github.com/zengoma/custom_backend_example/issues/1 , if you don't come right.